# autoconf save ./configure command line to config.h

Tags: compiling, autoconf

Some binaries save the command line used to configure them inside the binary (I don't remember any that do, otherwise I'd check the source). Is there a way to obtain the command line used as a macro in configure.ac?

For example, if I compile my code with

```
./configure --foo bar CXX=g++
```

I would like to save **--foo bar CXX=g++** to a macro in config.h so it can be output by the binary using a flag

```
./myprogram -V
Version 1.0, compiled using: "./configure --foo bar CXX=g++"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`configure` is essentially a shell script bootstrapped from M4 macros, so you can use `$*` to grab all the arguments to `./configure`. As per [the autoconf manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Initializing-configure) you should do this right after `AC_INIT`, e.g.:

```
AC_INIT([My Program], 1.0, ...)
config_flags="$*"
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([CONFIG_FLAGS],["$config_flags"],[Flags passed to configure])
```

This will `#define CONFIG_FLAGS` in config.h.